# DOCKER Runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a docker-compose file to run my web app locally and using a mono repo who's gonna build my front and back and deploy locally.
The thing is when I run **docker compose up** on the Linux machine of my school it's working but it's not on my Mac.

Can somebody help me ?
See down bellow for the details.

I got this working tree

```bash
   .env
   docker-compose.yaml
   /client
       Dockerfile
       packages.json
       /src
       /public
```

My docker-compose.yaml is the one bellow

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  reactjs:
    build: ./client
    container_name: reactjs
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    # volumes:
    #   - reactjs-data:/var/www
```

My client/Dockerfile is the one down bellow

```
FROM    node:alpine

EXPOSE  3000

RUN     apk add --no-cache bash
RUN     apk update
RUN     apk upgrade

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD     npm run start
```

When I do

> docker compose up

I got this error

```bash
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x39 pc=0x10526d690]

goroutine 11 [running]:
github.com/docker/buildx/builder.(*Builder).Validate(0x10646d8a0?)
        github.com/docker/buildx@v0.10.4/builder/builder.go:111 +0x20
github.com/docker/buildx/builder.New({0x10646d8a0?, 0x140000cc100}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x1400027ad50?})
        github.com/docker/buildx@v0.10.4/builder/builder.go:101 +0x290
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).doBuildBuildkit(0x1400052e360, {0x10645cd80, 0x14000532aa0}, 0x0?, {0x105c0f2b3, 0x4})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/build_buildkit.go:36 +0x68
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).build.func1({0x10645cd80, 0x14000532aa0}, {0x14000360e60, 0x7})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/build.go:112 +0x5b4
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*graphTraversal).run.func1()
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/dependencies.go:127 +0x5c
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
        golang.org/x/sync@v0.1.0/errgroup/errgroup.go:75 +0x5c
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
        golang.org/x/sync@v0.1.0/errgroup/errgroup.go:72 +0xa0
```

Here is my config

```
Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a
Docker Compose version v2.17.3
MacBook Pro M1 16Go, macOs Ventura 13.0.1
Docker Desktop is running, version Docker Desktop 4.19.0 (106363)
```

I would love some help...
I keep connected if anyone need more details or tests.
Thanks for all !

Comment: What does `docker buildx ls` and `docker buildx inspect` return?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, 
Thanks a lot for your answer !
Here is what I got when I do docker buildsx ls
default         docker                           
  default       default         running 23.0.5   linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
desktop-linux * docker                           
  desktop-linux desktop-linux   running 23.0.5   linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6

Comment: When I do **docker buildx inspect** on both of them, I got the same info than my previous message

Comment: can you edit the question with that info so it's easier to read? And also `docker plugin ls` output?